# What is *.gdb.fm file that appears to be associated with geometric network of ArcFM Water?

Tags: file-geodatabase, arcfm

I have been doing some work with a file geodatabase (test.gdb) which has a geometric network that I copied (using ArcCatalog or the Catalog window of ArcMap) from an ArcFM managed water network stored in SQL Server via ArcSDE at ArcGIS 10.2.x.

I have noticed that the test.gdb folder has an accompanying test.gdb.fm file, which appears to have been created at the same time as the geometric network was copied.

What is this `*.gdb.fm` file used for?

When the Catalog window of ArcMap is used to rename a file geodatabase, I notice that this file does not get renamed, which suggests that ArcCatalog is unaware of it.

Comment: Did you use ArcCatalog to do the copy, or ArcFM?

Comment: It sounds like a *rules* file. From my distant recollection of ArcFM there was a special file (or object in SDE) that contained extension specific information about the network and its features for consumption in ArcFM tools.

Comment: @Midavalo ArcCatalog (or the Catalog window of ArcMap) - not ArcFM

Comment: I agree with @MichaelStimson, it sounds like the rules file.  ArcFM will probably require it to be there to work.

Comment: @Midavalo Since I am only copying this geometric network out from ArcFM for non-ArcFM analysis, and not returning anything to ArcFM (or using ArcFM in any later steps of this particular workflow) it sounds like I do not need to worry too much if I forget to copy it with the file geodatabase.

Comment: That may depend on how much ArcFM has modified the network. Arcgis itself might not recognise it

Comment: @Midavalo ArcPy seems to be able to work with the geometric network OK, although I do have some traces (about 5-10%) that fail inexplicably: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260788